# Как отсортировать в стриме по двум полям с учетом null

Tags: java, java-stream

Здравствуйте. У меня есть лист таких объектов.

```
class Obj {
   Integer property1;
   Object property2;
}
```

Мне нужно отсортировать их в стриме. 
Мне нужно, отсортировать по *property1* в первую очередь, затем в  *thenComparing()*  добавить условие, чтобы сперва шли те обьекты, у которых property2 == null.

То есть вот сортировка по property1:

```
List<Obj> sortedList = list.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Obj::property1))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

У меня не получается cделать добавочную сортировку,  я вроде делаю простые вещи, но идея ругается, что  **non static method cannot be referenced from static context**

Помогите пожалуйста с сортировкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так.

```
Comparator<Obj> comparator1 = Comparator.comparing(Obj::getProperty1);
Comparator<Obj> comparator2 = comparator1.thenComparing((o1, o2) -> (o2.property2 == null) ? 1 : 0 + (o1.property2 == null ? -1 : 0));
list.stream().sorted(comparator2)...
```

Про ошибку *non static method cannot be referenced from static context* - в каком месте она возникает?

Comment: когда добавочную сортировку добавляю, то ругается. Сейчас глянул еще раз,то поле которое я хочу сортирововать по null, является lazy, в ОРМ. Возможно на это ругается...

Comment: Кажется, понял в чем у вас проблема. Вы используете тип поля Object. А нужен класс реализующий интерфейс Comparable.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
List<Obj> result =
        List.<Obj>of(new Obj(), new Obj(), new Obj())
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Obj::getProperty1)
                   .thenComparing(
                      Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(Obj::getProperty2))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```