# Как отсортировать List по двум полям одновременно?

Tags: java, list

Существует List - Список чатов. Для каждого пользователя этот список уникален.Каждый чат для пользователя может быть закреплён или не закреплён. Список отсортирован по дате последнего сообщения в чатах.

Как помимо сортировки даты добавить ещё сортировку по полю isPin? isPin - это boolean значение.

P.S. Сначала выводятся сообщения isPin - true, отсортированные по дате, а после : isPin - false и так же отсортированные по дате.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отсортировать в стриме по двум полям с учетом null](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/804789/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d1%81-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если первая сортировка выполняется по булевому полю в порядке `true / false`, то она выполняется в *обратном* порядке (reversed()), затем вызывается компаратор для сортировки по полю даты, которая также скорей всего должна выполняться в обратном порядке:

```java
List<Chat> chats = ... // 

chats.sort(Comparator
    // по убыванию isPin
    .comparing(Chat::isPin, Comparator.reverseOrder())
    // по убыванию времени последнего сообщения
    .thenComparing(Chat::getLastMessageTimestamp, Comparator.reverseOrder()) 
);
```

Аналогичного результата можно добиться при помощи менее многословного `Comparator.reversed()`, применив его к списку, отсортированному в прямом порядке по обоим полям:

```java
chats.sort(Comparator
    // по возрастанию isPin (false before true)
    .comparing(Chat::isPin)
    // по возрастанию времени последнего сообщения
    .thenComparing(Chat::getLastMessageTimestamp)
    .reversed() 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
sortedList = persons.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Post::isPin)
                      .thenComparing(Post::date));
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```